# C# output is somehow program name and class name

Tags: c#, string.format

I am trying to do the crazy formatting instructions my teacher gave me. After perusing for probably an hour (This is my first C# program), I came up with this line of code.

```
`Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + -longestTitle + "} | {1," + -longestAlbumTitle + "} | {2," + -longestArtist + "} | {3:0.00, 8} | {4," + -longestYearAndRating + "} |", songArray[arraySearcher].title, songArray[arraySearcher].albumTitle, songArray[arraySearcher].artist, songArray[arraySearcher].length, songArray[arraySearcher].yearAndRating));`
```

longestX is an int containing the number of characters of the `longestX` (`where x = title`, album, etc).

The output I would like looks something like this:

```
Stuff | morestuff | extrastuff |   5.92 | 1992:R  |
Stuf  | est       | sfafe      | 232.44 | 2001:PG |
S uf  | e         | sfe        |    .44 | 2001:G  |
```

(Where all padding is determined dynamically based on the longest title input by the user or file).

The output I get looks like this:

```
Program_Example.ClassName
Program_Example.ClassName
```

(or, specifically, Tyler_Music_Go.Song)

I have printed `songArray[arraySearcher]`.title in this same method, and it works fine.

Could someone please help me?

Full relevant code:

```
class Song {
    public string title, albumTitle, yearAndRating, artist;
    public float length;

    public Song(string titl, string albumTitl, string art, float leng, string yrNRating) 
    {
        title = titl;
        albumTitle = albumTitl;
        yearAndRating = yrNRating;
        length = leng;
        artist = art;
    }
}

//This class contains a Song array (with all Songs contained within), an array index, a search index, and ints to determine the longest of each category.
class SongList 
{
    Song[] songArray;
    private int arrayKeeper, longestTitle, longestArtist, longestAlbumTitle, longestYearAndRating, checker;
    int arraySearcher = 0;

    public SongList() 
    {
        songArray = new Song[10000];
        arrayKeeper = 0; 
        longestTitle = 0;
        longestArtist = 0;
        longestAlbumTitle = 0;
        longestYearAndRating = 0;
    }

    public void AddSong(string title, string albumTitle, string artist, float length, string yearAndRating)
    {
        songArray[arrayKeeper] = new Song(title, albumTitle, artist, length, yearAndRating);
        arrayKeeper++;
        checker = 0;

        //This section of code is responsible for formatting the output. Since the longest values are already known, the list can be displayed quickly. 
        //Once a song is deleted, however, previously calculated longest lengths still stand.
        foreach (char check in title)
        {
            checker++;
        }
        if (checker > longestTitle)
        {
            longestTitle = checker;
        }

        foreach (char check in albumTitle)
        {
            checker++;
        }
        if (checker > longestAlbumTitle)
        {
            longestAlbumTitle = checker;
        }

        foreach (char check in artist)
        {
            checker++;
        }
        if (checker > longestArtist)
        {
            longestArtist = checker;
        } 

        foreach (char check in yearAndRating)
        {
            checker++;
        }
        if (checker > longestYearAndRating)
        {
            longestYearAndRating = checker;
        } 

    }

    //public bool RemoveSong(string title)
   // {
    //}

    public void DisplayData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("|          Title          |          Album Title          |          Artist          |          Length           |          Year and Rating          |");
        for (arraySearcher = 0; arraySearcher < arrayKeeper; arraySearcher++)
        {
            //This line for testing purposes. (works)
            Console.WriteLine(songArray[arraySearcher].title);
            Console.WriteLine(songArray[arraySearcher].ToString());
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        //This line for testing purposes. (works)
        Console.WriteLine(songArray[arraySearcher].title);
        return String.Format("{0," + -longestTitle + "} | {1," + -longestAlbumTitle + "} | {2," + -longestArtist + "} | {3:0.00, 8} | {4," + -longestYearAndRating + "} |", songArray[arraySearcher].title, songArray[arraySearcher].albumTitle, songArray[arraySearcher].artist, songArray[arraySearcher].length, songArray[arraySearcher].yearAndRating);
    }
}
```

`

EDIT:

Well, now I feel all manor of stupid. I was overwriting the tostring() method for the SongList, and then calling the tostring method for Song. Guy who answered made me realize it. Thanks to everyone who gave me advice, though.

Comment: If you want your Song class to output something else then its own class name then you'll have to override the ToString() method.

Comment: I am overriding the tostring method. Maybe I should just post the whole thing.

Comment: Please break up your output function into multiple lines. Introduce some temporary variables for each column, like `formattedTitle`, and then combine them in the end.

Comment: I will. I just want the code to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either access a property directly (`songVariable.Title`) or  override `ToString()` in your song class to have that output the title.

```
public class Song
{
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that is the case, then why does Console.WriteLine(songArray[arraySearcher].title);
work in the line right before it? Is it different because of String.Format?